# How to fix sequential order of column with 'gaps' in a Ruby on Rails Migration

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, migration

I have a Ruby on Rails app (Rails version: 5.1.1 & Ruby version 2.3.1). Also using PostgreSQL if that matters. I'm having data integrity issues with a mapping table that maps students to selected courses where a column called `ranking` incorrectly has "gaps" in the ranking, and needs to be fixed to be sequential (per student) without any gaps.

**Example:** Let's say I have a table called `student_course_rankings` where a student selects multiple courses and ranks them based on their favorite course.

There's a unique constraint for `(student_id, course_id, ranking)`, so a student cannot select the same course twice.

`ranking` column just has a `NOT NULL` constraint, but no other constraints and is of type `integer`.

What is the best way to do this in a Ruby Migration?

```
class FixStudentCourseRankings < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change

    # Deletes duplicate courses (keeps the first)
    StudentCourse.where.not(
      id: StudentCourse.group(:course_id, :student_id).pluck('min(student_courses.id)')
    ).delete_all

    # Adds unique constraint so students can't accidentally select the same course more than once
    add_index :student_courses, [:course_id, :student_id, :ranking], :unique => true

    # HERE: Fix ranking order???
  end
end
```

Below is simplified version of my table and what it currently looks like with two students.

```
 id | student_id | course_id | ranking 
----+------------+-----------+---------
  1 |          1 |         2 |       1
  2 |          1 |         3 |       2
  3 |          1 |         5 |       4
  4 |          1 |         9 |       5
  5 |          1 |         6 |       6
  6 |          2 |         3 |       2
  7 |          2 |         6 |       4
  8 |          2 |         5 |       5
```

What I want it to actually look like:

```
 id | student_id | course_id | ranking 
----+------------+-----------+---------
  1 |          1 |         2 |       1
  2 |          1 |         3 |       2
  3 |          1 |         5 |       3
  4 |          1 |         9 |       4
  5 |          1 |         6 |       5
  6 |          2 |         3 |       1
  7 |          2 |         6 |       2
  8 |          2 |         5 |       3
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
Student.find_each do |student|
  # load all student_courses for a given student ordered by `ranking`
  student_courses = StudentCourse.where(student_id: student).order(:ranking)

  student_courses.each.with_index(1) do |student_course, index|
    # update the ranking by its position in the list
    student_course.update(ranking: index)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I found this to be the cleanest solution

Answer (score 3):

PostgreSQL has some [window finctions](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-window-function/) for ranking with/without gaps. You need one without gaps - [ROW_NUMBER](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-row_number/):

```
class FixStudentCourseRankings < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change

    # Deletes duplicate courses (keeps the first)
    StudentCourse.where.not(
      id: StudentCourse.group(:course_id, :student_id).pluck('min(student_courses.id)')
    ).delete_all

    execute <<~SQL
      UPDATE student_courses
      SET ranking = ranked.ranking
      FROM (
        SELECT
          id,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
            PARTITION BY student_id
            ORDER BY id ASC
          ) AS ranking
        FROM student_courses
      ) ranked
      WHERE student_courses.id = ranked.id
    SQL

    # Adds unique constraint so students can't accidentally select the same course more than once
    add_index :student_courses, %i[course_id student_id ranking], unique: true
  end
end
```

[Db-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/j9Lc7kRoHkRqNQFSR6fDp1/0)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would need to do the following things:

1. You could write a rake task to fix existing records with incorrect/missing ranks. I recommend writing a rake task since this would be a one time activity which would not really have an up/down toggle like that of migrations.
2. You could introduce validations for presence and uniqueness of rankings scoped to `course_id` and `student_id`. Reference: [Uniqueness validations in Rails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness)
3. You could write a custom validation on the `student_course_rankings` model to check that rankings do not have gaps.
4. Additionally, you would need to handle the order of rankings using suitable views.